# Search data in Firebase | android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have app and I am using Firebase Realtime database. I need get all data from `Search` and using this code:

```
      myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  Query query = myRef.orderByChild("Search");
  query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>>(){};
          test2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
```

I need to get it all in ArrayList, but now i am getting below exception

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while
>   deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

Database structure:

[image: view structure]

How can I fix this? I need to get all data from `Search` in `ArrayList`.
If you need I can post all code from activity and logs.

**Json:**

```
{
  "Search" : [ "Eggs", "Milk", "Apples", "Carrot", "Sugar", "Potato" ]
}
```

Comment: Add a sample of your database structure to the question, without knowing it it's impossible to give you a proper answer

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo okay. Did it

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Okay. I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `object` node is a direct child of your Firebase database root, to solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference searchRef = rootRef.child("object").child("Search");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
searchRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Eggs
Milk
Apples
Carrot
Sugar
Potato
```

Comment: In this fragment from your code `String value = ds.getValue();` the compiler indicated that `Required: java.lang.String
Found: java.lang.Object` Maybe I need write code like this: `String value = ds.getValue(String.class);`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Just edited my answer. Does it work with `getValue(String.class)`?

Comment: And in this fragment from your code `Log.d("TAG", list);` compiler indicated that `Wrong 2nd argument type, Found:' java.util.List<java.lang.String>', required: 'java.lang.String'`

Comment: Updated with `list.toString()`. Please see again my updated answer.